# How to copy the first few lines of a giant file, and add a line of text at the end of it using some Linux commands?

Tags: linux

How do I copy the first few lines of a giant file and add a line of text at the end of it, using some Linux commands?

Comment: In bash `head -n 100 yourfile.csv > shrunkfile.csv && echo 'morelines' >> shrunkfile.csv`

Answer (score 200, accepted):

The `head` command can get the first `n` lines. Variations are:

```
head -7 file
head -n 7 file
head -7l file
```

which will get the first 7 lines of the file called `"file"`. The command to use depends on your version of `head`. Linux will work with the first one.

To append lines to the end of the same file, use:

```
echo 'first line to add' >> file
echo 'second line to add' >> file
echo 'third line to add' >> file
```

or:

```
echo 'first line to add
second line to add
third line to add' >> file
```

to do it in one hit.

So, tying these two ideas together, if you wanted to get the first 10 lines of the `input.txt` file to `output.txt` and append a line with five `"="` characters, you could use something like:

```
( head -10 input.txt ; echo '=====' ) > output.txt
```

In this case, we do both operations in a sub-shell so as to consolidate the output streams into one, which is then used to create or overwrite the output file.

Answer (score 30):

I am assuming what you are trying to achieve is to insert a line after the first few lines of of a textfile.

```
head -n10 file.txt >> newfile.txt
echo "your line >> newfile.txt
tail -n +10 file.txt >> newfile.txt
```

If you don't want to rest of the lines from the file, just skip the tail part.

Comment: Subshells let you do this without reopening the output file: `(head -n10 file.txt ; echo "Some stuff" ; tail -n +10 file.txt) > newfile.txt`

Answer (score 5):

First few lines: [`man head`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/head/).

Append lines: use the `>>` operator (?) in Bash:

```
echo 'This goes at the end of the file' >> file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n '1,10p' filename > newfile
echo 'This goes at the end of the file' >> newfile
```